# Unable to start Windows 10 Search Indexing

Tags: windows, service

Recently when searching in File Explorer or the W10 search bar, I get the message `search indexing was turned off.` I have tried several things to fix this, however I am unable to turn on the service.

Things that could potentially be relevant:

- I recently migrated my C: drive to a new NVME SSD using Macrium Reflect.
- After migrating I gave my account ownership (using File Explorer) of all directories on the new C: drive since I will be the only one using the computer and want to give programs write permissions in certain folders they would otherwise be unable to access.

The first solution I tried was to Rebuild the Windows Search Index, however nothing occurs upon selecting that option. I looked in the Registry Editor to ensure that the SetupCompleteSuccessfully registry had a value of 0. Finally, I checked the Windows Search service from within the Services program. It is listed as `Automatic (Delayed Start)` and isn't running. When I attempt to run the service I get the following message:

[image: Error 21]

I then checked the Event Viewer, where under `Windows Logs>System` I see the following error:

[image: WSS Terminated Unexpectedly]

I also tried merging a new Windows Search .reg file, but nothing changed.

Comment: This has sadly nothing to do with programming. Off-Topic --> Hardware or Software

Comment: Is there anywhere else I could go for help? MS forum?

Comment: I think this might be a good one: https://superuser.com/  It is also part of the Stack Exchange Network (just like Stack Overflow).